# How to find vulnerable PHP parameter such as `.php?id=` as found in Kioptrix 3?

Tags: vulnerability, sql-injection, ctf

This is part of my preparation for OSCP.

According to https://www.vulnhub.com/entry/kioptrix-level-12-3,24/, Kioptrix 3 is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

However, I found that SQLi challenge on Kioptrix 3 is a little bit tricky as the `gallery.php?id=` parameter is quite "hidden".

```
http://kioptrix3.com/gallery/gallery.php?id=1&sort=photoid#photos
```

I've been browing manually and with burp suite, scan it with dirb, but did not see this (Photo id) as shown in the image below untill I read walk through from yeahhub.

[image]

Is there any tips to search vulnerable url like this?

Comment: Thanks @multithr3at3d, apparently I overlooked this. As you can see in the image above, the `Photo id` drop-down menu is located at the bottom of the page. Is there any automated way to scan for all parameters like this?

Comment: I realise you have now found the answer, however, there are ways to discover hidden parameters. e.g. https://markitzeroday.com/xss/finding/2018/02/03/hidden-xss.html or https://markitzeroday.com/xss/hidden/reflected/content-discovery/bug-bounty/2020/03/03/xss-hunting.html. There's also [this tool](https://github.com/PortSwigger/param-miner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "it is hidden". Monitoring/testing application routes and parameters should be a focus point in any assessment, plus it's right there in the URL.

You can discover/log URLs/links by browsing the site manually while using Burp Suite, or the "spider" feature, both of which should log all visited links under the "target" tab.

As far as determining if it is "vulnerable", that may take some further investigation. Parameters like that aren't inherently vulnerable, but their existence in CTF problems often signals a SQL injection problem. To determine whether an actual issue exists, you can [test it manually](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/v41/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/07-Input_Validation_Testing/05-Testing_for_SQL_Injection.html) or use a tool like sqlmap, which will test all parameters and find vulnerable ones.